# Remove object from array after uncheck checkbox

Tags: angular, object, angular-material

I know this is repeated question but I have tried multiple solution but still not worked my code.
I have a JSON object which has values of checkbox. So if any new checkbox is checked OR unchecked I am pushing that object in to new array.
But if I push any object by check checkbox and after uncheck checkbox then It is not removing from new array and vice versa.
Here is my html code

```
<div class="col-lg-2 m-3" *ngFor="let permission of resource.permissions; let i = index;">
  <mat-checkbox class="text-capitalize" (change)="permissionChange($event, permission)" [(ngModel)]="permission.allow">{{permission.name}}</mat-checkbox>
</div>
```

And here is my ts

```
permissionChange(ev, permissionObj) {
    if (ev) {
      // Pushing the object into array
      this.changedPermissions.push(permissionObj);
    } else {
      let el = this.changedPermissions.find(itm => itm === permissionObj);

      if (el) this.changedPermissions.splice(this.changedPermissions.indexOf(el), 1);
    }

    console.log("changedPermissions", this.changedPermissions);
  }
```

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MatCheckbox emits event when there is change in state of checkbox. It can be checked or unchecked. So your logic based on if(ev) is wrong.

What is happening here is that irrespective of the state of the checkbox (checked or unchecked), it always gets pushed to the array.

```
permissionChange(ev, permissionObj) {
    if (ev.checked) {
      // Pushing the object into array
      this.changedPermissions.push(permissionObj);
    } else {
      let el = this.changedPermissions.find(itm => itm === permissionObj);

      if (el) this.changedPermissions.splice(this.changedPermissions.indexOf(el), 1);
    }

    console.log("changedPermissions", this.changedPermissions);
}
```

EDIT:

If you want to push only the items which have different checked values than the original values, then first store the original values in an object.

```
private originalPermissions = [...this.resource.permissions];

permissionChange(ev, permissionObj) {
    let index = this.originalPermissions.findIndex(itm => itm.id === permissionObj.id);
    if (this.originalPermissions.allow !== permissionObj.allow) {
      // Pushing the object into array
      this.changedPermissions.push(permissionObj);
    } else {
      
      let el = this.changedPermissions.find(itm => itm.id === permissionObj.id);
      if (el) this.changedPermissions.splice(this.changedPermissions.indexOf(el), 1);
    }

    console.log("changedPermissions", this.changedPermissions);
}
```

Comment: Yes It is always going in push condition. But how can I handle this?

Comment: `if (ev.checked)`, see the docs:https://material.angular.io/components/checkbox/api#MatCheckboxChange (you see that `Output change` is of type `EventEmitter<MatCheckboxChange>`, so ev is of type `MatCheckboxChange`

Comment: This is working only for unchecked checkbox. Pushing when checked. But I also have checked checkbox. When I uncheck that, that object also should go in new array.